# How can you build a query for data created in the last 24 hours using Microsoft Graph query?

Tags: azure, datetime, graph, filter, active-directory

Trying to filter Azure AD audit events by only querying date that was created in the last 24 hours:

Example: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/signIns?$dateTime,-24

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

We can just subtract 24 hours from the current time and set it as the query filter. For example, if the current time is `2020-04-09T07:00:00Z`, the time minus 24 hours is `2020-04-08T07:00:00Z`. Then we can use the filter in graph api:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/auditLogs/signIns?$filter=createdDateTime ge 2020-04-08T07:00:00Z
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately that won't work as I need the call the exact date/time in the query dynamically (e.g. utcNow()) then subtract 24 hours.  Any way to do that?

Comment: Hi @user13264138 I don't think graph api can do it automatically. As a workaround, I think you can get the datetime utcNow()-24h in your code and put it as a param in the graph api after "ge".

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do this in an Azure Logic App and had to 1) Create a parameter of "startTime" 2) create 2 variables for the startDateTime and endDateTime 3) then use them in the Graph API call.

[Two variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qu1vQ.png)
[HTTP GET Call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qO4aC.png)